# Recommendation request for discussion platforms with event driven capabilities

Tags: forum

I am looking for recommendations on any discussion based platforms that include event driven functionality. Basically, we want discussion forums to become active throughout our site when certain activities occur.

A simple example would be date driven. When a pre configured date is reached, a discussion forum would appear on the designated section of the site.

Another example could be when a product sells x number of units, where x is a configurable threshold. When that rule is met, a discussion forum would appear on the product detail page.

I have looked at platforms like Disqus (and others in it's class), but nothing seems to include event driven functionality.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Should a whole and new forum (with the possibility to create several threads), or always the same forum, or only a single thread (e.g., like blog page comments) appear? // Should it be integrated in the actual page (with server-side code, e.g. PHP, or client-side with JS), or can the forum be embedded (e.g. in an `iframe`)? // Are you using a CMS currently? Do you need it as plugin for this CMS? Or are you fine with integrating it yourself?

Comment: All great questions.  I am not as worried about the implementation / integration right now.  We are in the beginning stages and still evaluating technology and approach.  I more curious on the functional capabilities described in the question (i.e. event driven).  I have not been able to find anything that fits those needs, and am looking to find **any solution, regardless of any other factors**.  Regarding your first question, the idea is that a whole new discussion thread would appear.  If it's related to other topics, that might be interesting, but not necessarily a requirement.